# How to add subview above tabbar and below navigationbar?

Tags: ios

My app has a right bar button item, when user taps it, an mask with opacity is added to view then slides down a droplist menu. I try to add these two views(maskview and droplist view) to `self.view`, but the tabbar appears on the top of the window.

An I try to add views to `self.view.window`, but navigation bar is masked during "droplist slide down" progress.

Any ideas?

**Update**: I wanna the following animations but with mask tabbar.

[image]

Comment: you can make height of "view with opacity" self.view.frame.size.height - navigation bar height.. then set y = nav bar height, and the add to self.view.window .. in this way  should cover only uitabbar

Comment: why not to add to the window considering origin y = navigation bar height

Comment: create a navigationcontroller, add viewcontroller to it as root view, add the mask view as the view of the viewcontroller , user transition delegate to customize animation, present the viewcontroller, present it from the [self navigationcontroller] of the viewcontroller you wish to present the mask over, set the view of the navigationcontroller to alpha = 0; then win. This is how you do it, but I won't show code because i dont' want to answer questions, it takes me 10 mins or less to do this.

Comment: hey,are you using autolayout ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your view in window,

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:yourView];
```

but make sure that view added after navigation bar frame. (For ex. your view's y origin = 64)